# Finding 1 number from each interval such that OR of all equals X

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, bit-manipulation

Given N integer intervals each of form [a,b] which contains integers from a to b .

From each interval we have to chose 1 number , such that bitwise OR of all chosen numbers = X . X is known .

I am stuck when we have multiple candidates from each interval for forming X.

Here's what I am able to think :
Algo :
1) from each interval eliminate numbers which have bit `j = 1` and bit `j = 0` in `X`.
2) now find the required no.

Problem arises in `step 2`.

> consider intervals : [1,3] [17,19] [15,18]
>   let X is 17 = (10001)
>
> 1
>   11
>
> 10001
>   10010
>   10011
>
> 01111
>   10000
>   10001
>   10010
>
> applying step 1 of algo possible candidates:
>
> 00001  (1)
>
> 10001  (17)
>
> 10000   (16)
>   10001   (17)
>
> step 2:
>   possible pairs :
>   1) 1 , 17 , 16
>   2) 1 , 17 , 17

Now we would have to pick each possible pair and check whether their OR is equal to X or not .
If pairs are large , it would take very much time to get answer . 
So , can some nice trick (to optimize above) or any other algo be applied to solve it ?

Comment: Your example doesn't work. Picking from the interval `[9,11]` will result in the 4-th least significant bit being set (`1xxx`), which isn't set in the target number 17.

Comment: well you are right , let me edit post . thanks for pointing .

Comment: I believe you can trivially reduce [k-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-SAT) to this problem, and k-SAT is NP-Complete, so nope, there are no 'nice tricks' really, just some useful heuristics (the same ones that apply to k-SAT).

Comment: This is also related to the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: @Dukeling, No, I said you can reduce k-SAT to this problem, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an entirely different way.

For each range `r[i] = (a, b)`, create a BDD `x[i]` expressing the fact that `a <= v[i] <= b`.

Create an other BDD expressing the fact that `OR[0 <= i < n](v[i]) == X`

Intersect all those BDD's. On the result, find any solution.

As a bonus, you can also:

- Find the number of solutions (without visiting them all)
- Find a solution of minimum (or maximum) weight
- Find a random solution, where every solution is equally likely

There is a downside, which is that for some inputs, the size of the BDDs will explode.

By the way, this is the way it's handled by [this website](http://goo.gl/HFZuFl) (it will switch to a SAT solver when the BDDs get too large, and then it will not be able to report the number of solutions any more).

Comment: please tell full form of BDD .

Comment: @ac_c0der full form? Anyway there's a good chapter about them in The Art of Computer Programming volume 4A, you can an old version of the relevant chapter [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc1b.pdf)